# What does ++letter[c - 'A']; mean in this C program?

Tags: c, char

I have the following program which counts the number of occurrences of every uppercase letter from a text file. 
I am commenting every line to understand what is happening with the program when it's executed, however I got lost in the following line `++letter[c - 'A'];`. I cannot get it, I think it's suppose to collect the letter and store the cum sum of the occurrence of this letter. But the notation c - 'A', it's a bit alien for me.

```
void main(argc,argv)
   int argc;
   char *argv[];
   {
   int c, i, letter[26];
   FILE    *ifp, *ofp, *fopen(); // pointers to in file and output file pointer

  if (argc != 3) /* if the number of arguments is not equal to 3 */
      printf("\nusage: %s infile outfile\n\n", argv[0]); // prints the following
      // message "usage letter infile outfile */
  else { // if the number of arguments is three 
      ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // opens the first file (pointer to file 
      // in reading mode //
      ofp = fopen(argv[2], "w"); // then opens the the second argument "second
      // file in writting mode. // 
      for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) /* initialize array to zero */
          letter[i] = 0; // makes every element in the array of 26 to 0, in other
          // words the counter for every letter to 0
      while (( c=getc(ifp)) != EOF) // gets the characters (next of a file)
          if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') // if the character found is an uppercase 
          // character between A and Z
              ++letter[c - 'A']; // 
      for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
          if (i % 6 == 0)
              fprintf(ofp, "\n");
          fprintf(ofp, "%5c: %5d", 'A' + i, letter[i]);
          }
          fprintf(ofp, "\n\n");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding:

```
if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') 
     ++letter[c - 'A'];
```

would be much better written as:

```
if( isupper( c ) )
{
    letter[ c-'A' ]++;
}
```

where `isupper()` is exposed via the header file `ctype.h`

regarding:

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i) 
   letter[i] = 0;
```

can be eliminated IF this:

```
int c, i, letter[26];
```

had been written as:

```
int c, i, letter[26] = {0};
```

Now for your question:

`letter[]` is an array for all the capital (ASCII) alphabet where `letter[0]` is a counter for the letter `A`.... `letter[25]` is a counter for the letter `Z`.

This calculation:

```
[ c-'A' ]
```

is taking the ordinal value in the variable `c` and subtracting the ordinal value of the capital letter `A`.  I.E. if `c` contains `A` then the result is 0 (which matches the index for the letter `A` in the array `letter[]`

The `++` says to increment the value in the array `letter[]`

The overall result is the entry in the array `letter[]` for the current letter in `c` will be incremented, thereby keeping a count of the number of occurrences of each capital letter encountered in the input

Comment: Nice explanation. I will rewrite some of lines of code according to your clarifications. I did not know the existence of `isupper`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It counts the number of occurrences of each letter.

---

`'A'` is just a number. On an ASCII-based machine, `'A'` is just another way of writing `65`.

In [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the 26 latin uppercase letters are found consecutively, so,

- `'A'-'A'` = `0`
- `'B'-'A'` = `1`
- `'C'-'A'` = `2`
- ...
- `'Z'-'A'` = `25`

(Note that this code doesn't work on [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) machines because the letters aren't contiguous in that encoding.)

So `letter[c - 'A']` produces a unique element of `letter` for each letter.

Finally, `++x` increments the value of `x`, so `++letter[c - 'A']` increments the element of `letter` that corresponds to the letter in `c`.

For example, if we read in `ABRACADABRA`, we'll end up with

```
int letter[26] = {
    /* A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M */
       5, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    /* N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z */
       0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array

```
int letter[26];
```

is supposed to contain a counter for each capital letter.

In ASCII representation every character is represented by a *8 bit integer* (base type `char`). And capital letters are represented by the compact range [65-90]:

- `A` is represented by value 65
- `B` is represented by value 66
- ... and so on

So, how to translate the input char to the index of your array of counters? Just by calculating `c - 'A'`: its value will be 0 for `A`, 1 for `B` and so on.

**In conclusion**, `++letter[c - 'A']` just increments the counter corresponding to character `c`.

Answer (score 2):

In the program there is declared an array

```
int c, i, letter[26];
```

that is evidently used to count letters in an input file.

In this loop

```
  while (( c=getc(ifp)) != EOF) // gets the characters (next of a file)
      if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') // if the character found is an uppercase 
      // character between A and Z
          ++letter[c - 'A']; //
```

if the character `c` contain a symbol between letters ['A', 'Z'] then to get the index in the array there is used the expression `c - 'A'`. For example if c is equal to 'A' then the expression will yield 0. If c is equal to 'B' then the expression will yield 1/ And so on. SO the element of the array with the index 0 corresponds to the letter 'A'. The element of the index 1 corresponds to the letter 'B'. The value of the element is increased in this statement

```
++letter[c - 'A'];
```

So each element of the array accumulate the frequency of the corresponding letter encountered in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is the character code that was read from the file. `'A'` is the character code of the letter `A`. So `c - 'A'` subtracts those two codes.

This takes advantage of the design that character codes for letters are sequential. So when `c` is `'D'`, `c - 'A'` will be `3`.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII Value of 'A' is 65.

`c` is the character code that was read from the file.

So when we write `++letter[c-'A']`
 here `c` gives us current character which also have some ASCII value.

Suppose c is 'B' ASCII code is 66

Then we will increase count of index `(66-65)`that is 1.